# How to find the system variables in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

I am a newbie to Magento. I am trying to find the various system variables used in Magento. For ex: how can i find the store opening hours? I know that it can be found in one of the email templates, but my question is, is there a way to know all the system variables that magento is using?

One of the use cases I am trying to solve is the payment / order details of a customer. Here we have several values such as order total, tax total, first order value, second order value, etc. How can i find the system variables of these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The settings you're describing can be found in the admin panel by going to 'Stores -> Configuration'.

These settings are detailed in Magneto's merchant documentation. https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/guide-overview.html

To answer your questions specifically —

1. The store operating hours can be found in 'Stores -> Configuration -> [General] General'. Scroll down and expand the 'Store Information' section and you will find what you're looking for.
2. For payment and order details, these are spread across several config areas depending on what you're trying to do. I'd start by getting familiar with the following config areas within 'Stores -> Configuration -> Sales': Sales, Tax, Checkout, Payment Methods, and Delivery Methods.

Some of these settings may require you to uncheck the 'Use system value' checkbox if you want to update them. If you do change values be sure to save the config page you're updating before moving on to another page. Also you'll likely need to refresh the config cache after making any changes to this area, Magento will prompt you if this is needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The link provided gives me some insights but I need the variable. For ex: Order ID is {{var order.increment_id}}, similarly what is it for the order value in the checkout page? And where can these variables be found?

Comment: @PrashanthK Apologies, I misunderstood what you were asking about. Could you clarify further? Are you asking about just seeing a list of which variables are available client-side during checkout? Or are you asking where these variable values are set from server-side?